# Can I run html file straight from tar.gz archive?

Tags: javascript, html

i have my `file.html` which run web page with some statistics. `Js` in that file get all libraries from `asserts` directory and app get data from `JSON` file. It's work nice if i run it in regular way. But I need to make an archive from that 3 components and then I want to run my file straight from tar.gz. Is that possible? I use standart `Archive Manager` if it make some difference. I got an error in my web console:

```
ReferenceError: $ is not defined
```

It just caught my first line in the script.

```
<script>
      $(function() {
            --tons of code here--
      });
</script>
```

Comment: you should use gfs or other way to mount archives

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you cannot run straight from the zip. So it works like this, when you open the file.html from .gz file only that is copied to the temporary folder. If you do <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>u</kbd>, which will give you the source code of your HTML and click on the JS file. you will not find it. So the error is due to that, JS cannot be loaded.

The way to solve it, well I cannot think there is some way. We usually zip things up to transfer it on FTP and the unzip it and run it then.

Comment: Thanks for answer, that's how i thought about it. But still hope someone resolve something like that or maybe it's another way to use js in archives.